# Double stochastic and Riemann integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

In solving a linear stochastic differential equation, I ended up on this integral:

$$\int_0^t\int_0^s e^{-\lambda(s-u)} dW_u ds $$

where $W_u$ is a Wiener process. I've tried solving the integral by writing it as:

$$\int_0^te^{-\lambda s}\left(\int_0^s e^{\lambda u} dW_u\right) ds $$

and integrating by parts by computing the derivative of $\int_0^s e^{\lambda u} dW_u$. However, this would require a sort of fundamental theorem of calculus for stochastic integrals, but I'm not sure it holds.

Comment: The Ito lemma serves as the Fundamental Theorem of Stochastic Calculus - I'd start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken there are two approaches that lead to two different
expressions for the double integral (which are of course equal):

1. You can apply stochastic Fubini:
   \begin{align}
   I_t&:=\int_0^t\int_0^s e^{-\lambda(s-u)}\,dW_u\,ds
   =\int_0^t\int_u^t e^{-\lambda(s-u)}\,ds\, dW_u\\
   &=\int_0^t\frac{1-e^{-\lambda(t-u)}}{\lambda}\, dW_u 
   \tag{1}
   =\frac{W_t-\int_0^te^{-\lambda(t-u)}\,dW_u}{\lambda}\,.
   \end{align}
2. Alternatively, if you set

$$
A_u=\frac{1-e^{-\lambda(t-u)}}{\lambda}
$$
you can use the integration by parts formula
\begin{align}\tag{2}
A_tW_t=\int_0^tA_u\,dW_u+\int_0^tW_u\,dA_u\,.
\end{align}
(The quadratic covariaton term $\langle A,M\rangle_t$ that is usually added here vanishes because $A_t$ has finite variation.) Since
$$
dA_u=-e^{-\lambda(t-u)}\,du\,,\quad A_t=0\,,
$$
we see that (2) becomes
$$
0=I_t-\int_0^tW_u e^{-\lambda(t-u)}\,du\,.
$$
**Summary:** The double integral can be written in the following alternative ways
$$
\boxed{I_t=\int_0^t\frac{1-e^{-\lambda(t-u)}}{\lambda}\, dW_u 
=\frac{W_t-\int_0^te^{-\lambda(t-u)}\,dW_u}{\lambda} }
$$
or
$$
\boxed{I_t=\int_0^tW_u e^{-\lambda(t-u)}\,du\,.}
$$